# MySQL ERROR 1290 (HY000) --secure-file-priv option

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write the results of MySQL script to a text file using the following code in my script.

```
SELECT p.title, p.content, c.name FROM post p
LEFT JOIN category c ON p.category_id=c.id
INTO OUTFILE 'D:\MySql\mysqlTest.txt';
```

However, I am getting the following

> ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

How do I solve this?

Comment: In case it can help you...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416379/errcode-13-select-into-outfile-issue/53760735#53760735

Comment: I posted a possible answer on another stackoverflow post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416379/errcode-13-select-into-outfile-issue/53760735#53760735

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a file `/etc/my.cnf` with the following content

```
[mysqld]
secure_file_priv            = ''
```

You can use this oneliner:

```
echo "[mysqld]\nsecure_file_priv\t\t= ''\n" | sudo tee /etc/my.cnf
```

And then restart mysql. If brew was used to install the mysql run the following command:

```
brew services restart mysql
```

Answer (score 63):

**Ubuntu 16.04 (EASY): Find out where you are allowed to write**

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;
+---------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv |
+---------------------------+
| /var/lib/mysql-files/     |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then, just write there

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM train INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/test.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
Query OK, 992931 rows affected (1.65 sec)

mysql>
```

**Mac OSX: Mysql installed via MAMP**

Find out where you are allowed to write

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;
+---------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv |
+---------------------------+
| NULL                      |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

NULL means you're screwed so you have to create the file "~/.my.cnf"

**Enable read/write for MySQL installed via MAMP (on Mac):**

1. open "MAMP" use spotlight
2. click "Stop Servers"
3. edit ~/.my.cnf (using vi or your favorite editor) and add the following lines:

   $ vi ~/.my.cnf

> ```
> [mysqld_safe]
> [mysqld]
> secure_file_priv="/Users/russian_spy/"
> ```

4. click "Start Servers" (in MAMP window)

**Now check if it works:**

a. start mysql (default MAMP user is root, password is also root)

```
$ /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

b. in mysql look at the white-listed paths

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;
+---------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv |
+---------------------------+
| /Users/russian_spy/          |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

c. Finally, test by exporting a table `train` into a CSV file

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM train INTO OUTFILE '/Users/russian_spy/test.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
Query OK, 992931 rows affected (1.65 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Or just set the `secure_file_priv = ""` in `~/.my.cnf` if you wish to export to any directory on your local workstation.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer! If anyone like me was able to export the file with the help of this answer but couldn't open it due to secure_file_priv, you may use "sudo cp -rf dir_cur_path dir_distenation_path" to use the file.

Answer (score 20):

1. Edit the (/etc/my.cnf file for CentOS) or (my.ini file for Windows)
2. Add 
   `secure-file-priv = ""` 
   line at the end
3. Stop mysql service using `systemctl stop mysqld`
4. Restart it using `systemctl start mysqld`

It will now allow you to import and export the data.

Comment: Is there a translation between kebab case and snake case?

Comment: I believe it should be "secure_file_priv" https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv

Answer (score 10):

Replace `"\"` to `"/"` in your file path.

Like this:

```
INTO OUTFILE 'D:/MySql/mysqlTest.txt';
```

Comment: Worked on Windows. MySQL gave no indication the path separator was the problem! The error message was only, "Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement" even though the output directory for `OUTFILE` was in `secure-file-priv` (configured in `my.ini`) and the MySQL user had full privileges.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot export data as it is configured in mysql config files. Open my.cnf config file and check.

Quote from MySQL [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv)

> This variable is used to limit the effect of data import and export operations, such as those performed by the `LOAD DATA` and `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` statements and the `LOAD_FILE()` function. These operations are permitted only to users who have the `FILE` privilege.
>
> `secure_file_priv` may be set as follows:
>
> - If empty, the variable has no effect.
> - If set to the name of a directory, the server limits import and export
>     operations to work only with files in that directory. The directory
>     must exist; the server will not create it.
> - If set to `NULL`, the server disables import and export operations. This
>     value is permitted as of MySQL 5.7.6.

(An empty value is the default, or it can be explicitly specified in my.cnf as `secure_file_priv=""`. A `NULL` value can be set with `secure_file_priv=NULL`.)

So, if you want to export data, then you need to comment this option and restart mysql server. Then you will be able to export.

Comment: Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html for more server system variable of mysql. There are quite intersting things that can be done using these variables.

Comment: I received the same error message on linux for not having file permissions correct for mysql (which was misleading). Make sure to allow mysql user read/write/execute as applicable, including for any parent folders.

Answer (score 4):

FOR MAC OS, if installed via HOMEBREW:

Edit my.cnf
PATH: /usr/local/etc/my.cnf

COPY this:

```
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
secure-file-priv = ''
```

SAVE

Explanation:
Secure_file_prive = NULL -- Limit mysqld not allowed to import and export
Secure_file_priv = '/tmp/' -- Limit mysqld import and export can only occur in /tmp/ directory
Secure_file_priv = '' -- does not restrict the import of mysqld

Answer (score 2):

This is the example of my SQL that worked perfectly in WAMP SERVER (windows):

```
SELECT display_name,user_email,user_registered FROM test_wp_users
ORDER BY user_registered ASC
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/wamp64/tmp/usersbyemail.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

PS: Note that bars in path should be left-to-right to work perfectly in MYSQL.

Comment: Because default value is platform specific and it is empty on Windows (means it can write anywhere), see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv

Answer (score 1):

In my my.ini I only had

```
# Secure File Priv.
```

and I tried to put:

```
# Secure File Priv.
secure-file-priv = ""
```

and

```
# Secure File Priv.
secure-file-priv = NULL
```

without making it work.

I finally deleted the line and left alone:

```
secure-file-priv = ""
```

Working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `secure_file_priv` is set to NULL

mysql> show variables like `secure_file_priv`;

```
| secure_file_priv | NULL  |
```

You must stop mysql server

```
shell>/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

Then restart mysql with the option defining where you want your files to be written to, for example to /tmp

```
shell>/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start --secure-file-priv=/tmp
```

Then in mysql terminal you should see where your files can now be written to

mysql> show variables like `secure_file_priv`;

```
| secure_file_priv | /private/tmp/ |
```

On Mac you can find this folder by using Go To Folder `/private/tmp` in Finder

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0 and you will find my.ini file. Open my.ini file in text editor (recommended notepad++) and then search for secure_file_priv and then replace will secure_file_priv="" and then save the file.

and restart your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who is trying to export - from dbeaver.

You can right-click the query, and get the exact output of custom query as export.

[image: dbeaver export SQL query]

No need for another conf file.