# How to deal with The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement on a Mac

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm looking to turn off secure-file-priv on mySQL 5.7.17. I've tried other suggestions for adding secure-file-priv="" to my.cmf, however mySQL refuses to start up afterwards:

```
bash-3.2# mysql
mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'secure-file-priv='
bash-3.2#
```

Other posts suggested secure_file_priv in stead but I get the same response from mySQL: unknown variable.

I've also tried adding `--secure-file-priv=/path/to/folder` to mySQL's launch daemon, but I get the same error.

Does anyone know how to turn this cumbersome feature off on the Mac version of mySQL?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**For MySQL installed via MAMP (on Mac):**

1. open "MAMP" use spotlight
2. click "Stop Servers"
3. edit ~/.my.cnf (using vi or your favorite editor) and the following lines:

   $ vi ~/.my.cnf

> ```
> [mysqld_safe]
> [mysqld]
> secure_file_priv="/Users/russian_spy/"
> ```

4. click "Start Servers" (in MAMP window)

**Now check if it works:**

a. start mysql (default MAMP user is root, password is also root)

```
$ /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

b. in mysql look at the white-listed paths

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;
+---------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv |
+---------------------------+
| /Users/russian_spy/          |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

c. Finally, test by exporting a table `train` into a CSV file

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM train INTO OUTFILE '/Users/russian_spy/test.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
Query OK, 992931 rows affected (1.65 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error.

It was caused to variable in the wrong section.

It worked only when it under `[mysqld]`:

```
[mysqld]
secure_file_priv="/home"
```

Also, I noticed, that it wasn't working, when I tried to set it to empty string - it only worked, when it had actual path

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out (sort of...).

it is `secure-file-priv = ""` but I had to uninstall mySQL and reinstall then use mySQL workbench to set it in order to avoid the unknown variable error.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to upload files as a BLOB I was first getting NULL values when inserting the BLOBs. Then, when trying to set the secure-file-priv in my.cnf I was getting errors like:

```
mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'secure-file-priv=
```

It was changed when placing the secure_file_priv under the MySQLD section:

```
[mysqld]
secure_file_priv="/data/upload/"
```

The second part that I needed to do was to disable Apparmor

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

Third (and this is logic), the files to upload need to be in the secure-file-priv folder:

You can check if it is working by executing the following command:

```
mysql> SELECT LENGTH(LOAD_FILE("/data/upload/image.png"));
--------------
SELECT LENGTH(LOAD_FILE("/data/upload/image.png"))
--------------

+-----------------------------------------------+
| LENGTH(LOAD_FILE("/data/upload/image.png")) |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|                                        389893 |
+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And that solved it for me. I hope this is useful to you too.