# Can't create/write to file '/home/vagrant/folder/test.csv' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied"

Tags: mysql, csv, vagrant

I'm trying to export CSV from MySQL database using INTO OUTFILE.
I would like to store reports, for example, in /home/vagrant/test folder.

Now, I tried to change 
`secure_file_priv = ''` and nothing, i can only store to /tmp.

If I change `secure_file_priv = '/home/vagrant/test'` i can not restart mysqld?

Do you have any idea how to solve this ?
I guess there is some problem with permissions, but I'm not sure where.

(Queries are correct, so there is no need to show them here)

Comment: What user is the mysql process running as? What are the permissions on that folder?

Comment: mysql user is mysql.
drwxrwxrwx  2 mysql   mysql    4096 Mar 30 00:37 test

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2268735/6560549

Comment: It's possible that you have apparmor, which might restrict where mysql can write. Do you have an `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin/mysqld` file?

Comment: Actually i think I do, but file is empty, only comments there. Ill check it out in the morning. Thank you @Evert